# Append items of array or exclude if already exists

Tags: javascript, lodash

as I describe my problem in title, I need implement following algorithm:

I got some array of elements, e.g.:

```
let arr1 = [
  {id:1, foo1: '...', foo2: '...'}, 
  {id:2, foo1: '...', foo2: '...'}, 
  {id:3, foo1: '...', foo2: '...'}, 
];
```

in somewhere in my application I got another array arr2 which can contains elements which already are in arr1.

```
let arr2 = [
  {id:1, foo1: '...', foo2: '...'}, 
  {id:4, foo1: '...', foo2: '...'}, 
  {id:5, foo1: '...', foo2: '...'}, 
];
```

In case arr1 contains each element of arr2 I need exclude these elements from arr1. And in second case where arr2 contains least one element which is also not in arr1, all elements of arr2 will append to arr1.

I tried lodash's function `_.xorBy(arr1, arr2, 'id')` which doesn't work in all cases. I looked for in lodash's docs some another function for my needs but I didn't found anything.

Here is my expected behavior (I use just number but in real app there objects with this ids):

- given: arr1=[1,2,3,4,5] and arr2=[1,2,3] => resultArr=[4,5]
- given: arr1=[1,2,3,4,5] and arr2=[1,2,6] => resultArr=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
  //6 is different so append all

Can you help me solve my problem, or show my some elegant way to do that? Thanks in advice.

Comment: Do you also want to update the value, also will they have the same number of elements

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri no objects with same id are also with same properties so update is not required

Comment: The issue is that you try to mix two behaviors in one. You should create a function for each case, and then a 3rd one which will test the behavior needed.

Comment: I agree with @ChrisR, this seems like you may be backing yourself into a corner. Whenever you call this function it will return two totally different result sets. Either it returns an exclusive set or an inclusive set, I expect the logic that comes after this will become muddled due to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the [`_.difference()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#difference) array length between `arr2` and `arr1` is greater than `0`, return a [`_.union()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#union) of the arrays. If not return the `_.difference()` between `arr1` and `arr2`.

**Note 1:** `_.difference(arr2, arr1)` is not equal to `_.difference(arr1, arr2)` because the order and references of result values are determined by the first array.

**Note 2:** The example uses arrays of primitives. For arrays of objects use the `By` versions - [`_.differenceBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#differenceBy) and [`_.unionBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#unionBy) with the property iteratee shorthand - `_.differenceBy(arr1, arr2, 'id')`.

```js
const incEx = (arr1, arr2) => 
  _.difference(arr2, arr1).length > 0 ? 
    _.union(arr1, arr2) 
    : 
    _.difference(arr1, arr2);

console.log(incEx([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3]));
console.log(incEx([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,6]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Right! For their real use case (objects with ids) they're going to use `By` versions of diff/union.

Answer (score 1):

A plain Javascript solution with [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```js
function merge(array1, array2) {
    var ids1 = new Set(array1.map(({ id }) => id)),
        ids2 = new Set(array2.map(({ id }) => id));

    return array2.every(({ id }) => ids1.has(id))
        ? array1.filter(({ id }) => !ids2.has(id))
        : array1.concat(array2.filter(({ id }) => !ids1.has(id)));
}

var array1 = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }],
    array2 = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 5 }];

console.log(merge(array1, array2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

> In case arr1 contains each element of arr2 I need exclude these
>   elements from arr1.

To check if all `arr2` is contained in `arr1`

```
var hasAllValues = arr2.every( s => !!arr1.find( t => t.id == s.id ) )
```

`hasAllValues` is true if all `arr2` is in contained in `arr1`

Use `filter` to remove those values in `arr1`,

```
arr1 =  arr1.filter( s => arr2.find( t => t.id == s.id ) );
```

> And in second case where arr2 contains least one element which is
>   also not in arr1, all elements of arr2 will append to arr1.

find the values of arr2 which are not arr1 using

```
var arr3 =  arr2.filter( s => !!arr1.find( t => t.id == s.id ) );
arr1 = arr1.concat( arr3 );
```

**So, final solution would be**

```
var hasAllValues = arr2.every( s => !!arr1.find( t => t.id == s.id ) )
if ( hasAllValues )
{
   arr1 =  arr1.filter( s => !arr2.find( t => t.id == s.id ) );
}
else
{
   var arr3 =  arr2.filter( s => !arr1.find( t => t.id == s.id ) );
   arr1 = arr1.concat( arr3 );
}
```

**Demo of scenario 1**

```js
let arr1 = [{
    id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2
  },
  {
    id: 3
  },
  {
    id: 4
  }
];
let arr2 = [{
    id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 4
  }
];

var hasAllValues = arr2.every(s => !!arr1.find(t => t.id == s.id))
if (hasAllValues) {
  arr1 = arr1.filter(s => !arr2.find(t => t.id == s.id));
} else {
  var arr3 = arr2.filter(s => !arr1.find(t => t.id == s.id));
  //console.log(arr3)
  arr1 = arr1.concat(arr3);
}

console.log(arr1);
```

**Demo of scenario 2**

```js
let arr1 = [{
    id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2
  },
  {
    id: 3
  }
];
let arr2 = [{
    id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 4
  },
  {
    id: 5
  }
];

var hasAllValues = arr2.every(s => !!arr1.find(t => t.id == s.id))
if (hasAllValues) {
  arr1 = arr1.filter(s => !arr2.find(t => t.id == s.id));
} else {
  var arr3 = arr2.filter(s => !arr1.find(t => t.id == s.id));
  //console.log(arr3)
  arr1 = arr1.concat(arr3);
}

console.log(arr1);
```

Comment: I think it has to do with the use of `==` instead of `===` and the fact that you put a `find` inside an `every` and a `filter`. And maybe the `!!`. But I didn't downvote, so just tryin' to help here. ^^'

Comment: @ChrisR I don't think usage of `find`, `every` and `filter` is wrong. Why do you think this is the reason for downvote?

Comment: You combine them, doing a loop inside a loop (which is never a good idea). But hey, it's just guesses.